# Fields blank in email delivered with PHP form

Tags: php, forms

I apologize in advance if this is an easy fix as I'm somewhat new to learning PHP. I found related questions and tried those answers, but none applied to my issue.

I am receiving an email from my contact form where some of the fields show up and some do not. On the Address field, I only receive the country, and for the Date Available field, I only receive the year. These are the current issues. I thought maybe it could be the input id, but it is only those two giving me a problem right now.

I sincerely appreciate any help you can offer.

PHP:

```
    <?php

$myemail  = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Employment Application Submission from Your Website";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$position   = check_input($_POST['position']);
$refer    = check_input($_POST['refer']);
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$address    = check_input($_POST['address']);
$phone    = check_input($_POST['phone']);
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$dateavail    = check_input($_POST['dateavail']);
$social    = check_input($_POST['social']);
$dob    = check_input($_POST['dob']);


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}


/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Position Applied For: $position
Referred by: $refer
Name: $name
Address: $address 
Phone: $phone
E-mail: $email
Date available: $dateavail
SSN: $social
DOB: $dob

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>

   <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form_884913" method="post" action="send_form_email1.php" class="appnitro">



            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="position">Position Applied For </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="position" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="refer">How were you referred to us? </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="refer" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="name">Full Name (first, middle, last) </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="address">Address </label>

        <div>
            <input id="element_4_1" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">Street Address</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="element_4_2" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">Address Line 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_4_3" name="address" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">City</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <input id="element_4_4" name="address" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">State / Province / Region</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_4_5" name="address" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
            <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">Postal / Zip Code</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <select class="element select medium" id="element_4_6" name="address"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
            </select>
        <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">Country</label>
    </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="phone">Phone </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_5_1" name="phone" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="element_5_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_5_2" name="phone" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="element_5_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_5_3" name="phone" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_5_3">####</label>
        </span>

        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="email">E-Mail Address </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="dateavail">Date Available to Start </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_7_1" name="dateavail" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text"> /
            <label for="dateavail">MM</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_7_2" name="dateavail" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text"> /
            <label for="dateavail">DD</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_7_3" name="dateavail" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
            <label for="dateavail">YYYY</label>
        </span>

        <span id="calendar_7">
            <img id="cal_img_7" class="datepicker" src="calendar.gif" alt="Pick a date.">   
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Calendar.setup({
            inputField   : "element_7_3",
            baseField    : "element_7",
            displayArea  : "calendar_7",
            button       : "cal_img_7",
            ifFormat     : "%B %e, %Y",
            onSelect     : selectDate
            });
        </script>

        </li>       <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description" for="social">Social Security Number </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_8" name="social" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div>
```

(I did not display the entire form for length purposes)

Comment: use different name for input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several input's with the same `name`. You need to give each input element a unique name. If you have multiple elements with the same name only the last one will be sent to the server.

**An easy solution:**

Change your PHP:

```
$address = check_input($_POST['address']." ".$_POST['address2']." ".$_POST['address3']." ".$_POST['address4']." ".$_POST['address5']);
```

Change your HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="element_4_1" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
    <label for="address" style="font-size: 12px;">Street Address</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input id="element_4_2" name="address2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
    <label for="address2" style="font-size: 12px;">Address Line 2</label>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <input id="element_4_3" name="address3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
    <label for="address3" style="font-size: 12px;">City</label>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <input id="element_4_4" name="address4" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
    <label for="address4" style="font-size: 12px;">State / Province / Region</label>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <input id="element_4_5" name="address5" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
    <label for="address5" style="font-size: 12px;">Postal / Zip Code</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great. Sorry, newbie to PHP and sometimes hard to find an answer for your exact problem when you don't know what you're looking for. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `<input>` with the same name:

```
<input id="element_4_1" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
<input id="element_4_2" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
```

Since the `name` is what appears as the key in `$_POST`, you're essentially overwriting all of your inputs with the LAST `name="address"` that appears in the form.

Each input must have a unique name. Which you already have in your `$foo = $_POST[...]`, so why you don't have the matching names in your form is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

you are using same names for input fields .. give different names for name attributes in input fields.

```
 <input id="element_4_1" name="streetaddress" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
  <input id="element_4_2" name="addressline2" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
```

while receiving in php.. get one by one. example

```
$doorNo = $_POST['streetaddress'];
$streetName= $_POST['addressline2'];
```

like wise for all fields.. same applies to all other issues.